# HTML5 state of current implementations

Tags: html

is there a site where you can see the implementation state of all HTML5 features inside the browsers. (Video, audio, drag and drop, web storage, flexible box etc)

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. http://slides.html5rocks.com

Comment: well, yeah thats a really nice presentation but it doesn't show what is currently implemented in the browsers and how standardconform it is. (still worth reading and a few points ;))

Comment: @Stefan The website has a lot of info on that.  Each specific API shows you which Browser supports it. Example the notification API see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/  :)